# robolectric java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/b

Tags: crash, thrift, robolectric

#### Description

run unit test failed!!!

#### Robolectric & Android Version

build.gradle config:

testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3"

compileSdkVersion 25

buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

minSdkVersion 18

targetSdkVersion 23

stack message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/b
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callConstructor(ReflectionHelpers.java:319)
at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ShadowImpl.newInstanceOf(ShadowImpl.java:20)
at org.robolectric.shadow.api.Shadow.newInstanceOf(Shadow.java:35)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplication.registerBroadcastReceivers(ShadowApplication.java:138)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplication.bind(ShadowApplication.java:127)
at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter.bind(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:71)
at org.robolectric.android.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:107)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:289)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:203)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:109)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:36)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.thrift.b
at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.getByteCode(SandboxClassLoader.java:161)
at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.maybeInstrumentClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:108)
at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.findClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:101)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 32 more

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: I remove `@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)` , and the exception is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, cause I have a third party receiver referring to org.apache.thrift.b.

Comment: How did you get around it?